# How to reload files tree in CodeLite?

Tags: file, directory, codelite

Is it possible to reload or update folders in the CodeLite environment?

I mean, add newly added files to the project and remove files or folders that doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click in the project folder (blue one). click, in the context menu click "reconcile project". The wizard will take care of the rest.